# docker-compose safe upgrade (with ability to revert)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers, podman

I'm using `docker-compose` for multiple services that are regularly updated. I'm using the `:latest` tag which gets the latest image when `docker-compose pull` is issued:

```
services:
  calibre-web:
    image: lscr.io/linuxserver/calibre-web:latest
    container_name: calibre-web
...
```

I'm aware that some consider the `:latest` tag to be an anti-pattern but I've found it the most convenient way to keep on top of updates in my case as I'm the only user relying on these images.

However, I would like an easy workflow to revert to the previous known working image if the update doesn't work.

For example, is it possible to tag the current container (e.g. `:last-known-working`), update with `docker-compose pull && docker-compose up -d --force-recreate`, test, then either accept or revert easily and accurately?

Any other suggestions for solving this problem in a different way would be useful.

Comment: It realllly seems like it would be better not to use `:latest`. Maybe you can write a script to update the tag for you?

Comment: Are you using any git repo like github or gitlab for maintaining your dockercompose file. These both have solutions like `dependabot` or `renovate` which can check your porjects pinned versions and check for updates. They can also automatically create a PR/MR in the repo which wyou could then test either through CI/CD or use the PR/MR notification as your trigger to manually test

Comment: docker compose files are git VCed but not in a repo currently. I'll look at those

Comment: I'm going to give renovate a go. It is useful (and invaluable for anything more than a home server) to be able to keep a defined state (including a specific version, rather than latest) as a git commit but is a bit overkill for my use

Comment: So renovate looks like a great project but it's no good in my case as doesn't support aarch64. Any other suggestions?